# What is "better than I could have ever created" in one or two words?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

It sounds pretty lengthy-- how can I trim it down?

Comment: Single word requests should come with a complete sentence that also gives some context.

Answer (score 2):

An example such as “It is better than I could ever have created” is not excessively long. To shorten it you have a choice of several words that may depend on context. The key verbs are shown in italics. Here are examples of their use:

It *surpasses* any effort of mine

It *transcends* my efforts

It *eclipses* my creations

You might also use slightly lower register verbs such as *outclasses*, *outshines* or *beats*.

I do not repeat easily obtained dictionary definitions of these words but hope that they help you.